# MySQL ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, bitnami

I noticed this issue when my Wordpress server started throwing aa MySQL error. To try to debug Wordpress, I attempted to connect manually.

I get the following:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306                                                                                                                                         
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've also tried no -h option and 127.0.0.1

It looks like MySQL is running.

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql                                                                                                                                                           
mysql    14743     1  0 15:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
bitnami  14939 13882  0 15:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto
```

mysql-server is installed, but `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock` does not exist.

It looks like MySQL is listening on the correct port.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1,IIq{;Rh�k>5/)"m"[&J#mysql_native_password

!#08S01Got packets out of orderConnection closed by foreign host.
```

[Following the suggestion here:](https://community.bitnami.com/t/mysql-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket/4498/2)

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache already running
mysql not running
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql
2017-02-14T16:53:25.064586Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
2017-02-14T16:53:25.233250Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
2017-02-14T16:53:28.400598Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
Monitored mysql
```

Here are a few choice lines from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log. It looks like theres a conflict.

```
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274720Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274778Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274835Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274888Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274901Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2017-02-14T17:03:31.274952Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: `sudo find / -name mysql.sock` where is it located?

Comment: And are there any hints in `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log`?

Comment: There are no results for `sudo find / -name mysql.sock`, info from the log was dded to the main post.

Comment: @Jones Don't forget to ping people by putting an @ and their name or they won't be notified of your reply.

Comment: According to your ps, it's running, but there's no sock file. Try `sudo service mysql stop`, or kill the process `sudo kill 14743`. Then run the script again.

Comment: `sudo service mysql stop` and `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql` got it working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you already have a mysql server running which is not the bitnami one. You should stop that service first before start the mysql server from bitnami.

You can try to stop with:

`$ sudo service mysql stop`

If it doesn't work you can kill the process:

`$ sudo kill 14743`

And finally start the bitnami mysql server with this command:

`$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql`

After this server is running you should be able to connect without problems.

Answer (score 3):

Before doing anything first check space. Make sure it is not used 100%

```
df -h
```

[image]

If space is available.

For Chcecking Mysql is running or not.

```
ps xufa | grep mysql
```

Restart mysql

```
sudo service bitnami restart mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, all you need is a restart.
Try the following.

```
sudo opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
```

Followed by

```
sudo opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

You can also do a restart but I have had instances where restarts have not worked but stopping and starting have worked.